# panelGroup mess up my layout

Tags: css, jsf

I have standard page layout: header + 2 blocks (left and right). Code are below

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">
    <div id="center_header">
        <h:outputText value="#{ScholarActiveHub.selectedGroup.groupName}"/>
    </div>

    <div id="center_left">

    </div>

    <div id="center_right">
        <h:dataTable value="#{ScholarActiveHub.groupMembers}" var="item" style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
            </h:column>                    
        </h:dataTable>
    </div>     
</h:panelGroup>
```

I want turn on and off these `<div>` tag all at once, so I nested them inside a `panelGroup`. Now it turn on and off these `<div>` alright, but layout is all mess up. Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't happen. In your code example, the `<h:panelGroup>` shouldn't render anything. But if it contains an attribute which should end up in HTML, like `id`, then it will render a `<span>` element. Check the generated HTML output in the webbrowser. Does it all look right? Does your CSS take this into account? Maybe you want it to be a block element as well? If you add `layout="block"` to the `<h:panelGroup>` then it will render a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`. This may be more what you want.

Comment: `layout="block"` is exactly what I want. Srry, the `rendered=#{false}` just to demonstrate how I want everything to turn on and off at the same time. So `panelGroup` will always generate `<span>` unless you put `layout=block`, correct?

Comment: Only if you specify attributes which ends up in HTML. In your code snippet there is none (maybe you oversimplified it?), so it won't generate anything. But if you for example have an `id`, `styleClass`, etc, then it will generate a `span`.

Comment: That make sense. I have `style` attributes in my JSF code. Thank you